# PHP convert '../folder/file.php' into url

Tags: php

So I'm working on a website currently on localhost. I'm testing an image uploader, and I have to generate an URL for the image to be displayed..

```
etc etc..
     // move the file to folder <- it works
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '../../common/img/post-uploads/' . $name);

    // Generate response.
    $response = new StdClass;
    $response->link = MAINFOLDER . '/common/img/post-uploads/' . $name; // but I need an URL here..?:/
    echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
```

As you see, when I move the uploaded file to path, it works like this "../../common/img/post-uploads"

but at the end, I would like to get an URL.. so the final diplayed image would be like

> < img src="http://localhost/mysite/common/image/post-uploads/image.jpg">

is it possible somehow? like

```
$response->link = convertThisToURL('../../common/img/post-uploads/' . $name);
```

? :/

Answer (score 0):

Since you show two `../` I would think that this item is outside of your domain.  There isn't a way to do that unless the full link is inside the domain directory.

Per your comment below then answer then would be a symbolic link.

```
ln -s /localhost/mysite/common/img/post-uploads /localhost/mysite/images
```

For example. then just post that nice new url without all that ../ stuff

Comment: No no..

The image uploader file is in the

localhost/mysite/admin/php/uploader.php

And I would like to get an URL for this:

localhost/mysite/common/img/post-uploads/image.jpg